# Show video overlay from clicking linkButton

Tags: c#, javascript, video, overlay

I have a page with a gridview.
On of the columns is showing an play icon depending on whether there is an video-url in the database. This part is :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-CssClass="video" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtVideoUrl" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:clicker('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qySK7GWFEAg')" ><img class='<%# Eval("Class", "{0}")  %>' src='<%# Eval("VideoImage", "{0}")  %>' alt="Video" title='<%# Eval("ToolTip", "{0}")  %>' /></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The javascript that should handle this is :

```
function clicker(theUrl) {
    var thediv = document.getElementById('displaybox');
    if (thediv.style.display == "none") {
            thediv.style.display = "";
            thediv.innerHTML = "<table width='100%' height='100%'><tr><td align='center' valign='middle' width='100%' height='100%'><object width='640' height='360'><param name='movie' value='" + theUrl + "'></param><param name='allowFullScreen' value='true'></param><param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'></param><embed src='" + theUrl + "' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' width='640' height='360' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true'></embed></object><br><br><a href='#' onclick='return clicker();'>CLOSE WINDOW</a></td></tr></table>";
    } else {
        thediv.style.display = "none";
        thediv.innerHTML = '';
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, when i click the button i see the gray overlay and the video field, but before anything is shown the overlay is closed again. I must be missing something, but have no clue what....

One more piece of info (don't know if it is relevant) : i had to add the following to the code behind to get it 'working' so far :

```
protected void gv_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

PS next step is getting the url from the database, so i can add different links to different icons.